# I don't understand how the size is equal to float and not short int as the size of i is short int

Tags: c

I don't understand how the size is equal to `float` and not `short int` as the size of i is `short int`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    short int i = 2;
    float f = 3;
    if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float))
        printf("float\n");
    else if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(short int))
        printf("short int\n");
}
```

Comment: Ternary operator only has one type. In your example `short int` is promoted to `float`.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't a function so it can't evaluate a runtime value like `x == 2`

Comment: @cleblanc The ternary operator has a defined type at compile time. `sizeof` is not evaluated (except for VLAs).

Comment: @Osiris sure it does and that's why it compiles, I'm just pointing out that it won't do what she seems to want which is evaluate `x == 2`

Answer (score 2):

The type of a conditional expression is always defined at compile time. 
The expression `(x == 2) ? f : i` is of type `float` since `i` is promoted.

`sizeof` is not evaluated (except for VLAs), so it is not even checked if `x == 2`.